# Caching mapper output

Tags: java, mapreduce, store

I notice that I am running the same mapping job very often on the same  (big amount of) data, and change the reducer behavior. Is it possible to store the mapper output on HDFS in some seamless way so that the reducer can read it? How would I go about creating a reducer-only job which reads key-listofvalue pairs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To define reducer only job you need to define identity mapper as mentioned below:
job.setMapperClass(Mapper.class)

And for your problem of using Mapper one time data, you can run one Map only job first by specifying:
job.setNumReducer(0)
And, after getting its output, use output directory of this job as input directory for Reducer only job.

P.S. Methods name mentioned above may not be the same as that in the API as I dont have API currently with me. Plz verify before using them.